# Pytsk install failure: Unable to locate SleuthKit header files using ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, computer-forensics

Currently having issues locating SleuthKit (3.2.3-2ubuntu1) header files when attempting to install pytsk in Ubuntu 12.04. This is the installation error I am receiving:

```
Downloading/unpacking pytsk

      Downloading pytsk-4.1.3-20140506.tar.gz (142kB): 142kB downloaded
      Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pytsk/setup.py) egg_info for package pytsk
         Traceback (most recent call last):
             File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
             File "/tmp/pip_build_root/pytsk/setup.py", line 117, in <module>
                raise EnvironmentError('Unable to locate SleuthKit header files.')
         EnvironmentError: Unable to locate SleuthKit header files.
         Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
         Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/pytsk/setup.py", line 117, in <module>

    raise EnvironmentError('Unable to locate SleuthKit header files.')

EnvironmentError: Unable to locate SleuthKit header files.
```

Log from /home/some_jerk/.pip/ reads as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/pip run on Thu Feb 12 12:12:28 2015
Downloading/unpacking pytsk
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytsk/
  URLs to search for versions for pytsk:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytsk/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytsk/
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pytsk/pytsk-4.1.3-20140506.linux-x86_64.tar.gz#md5=dbc9cce02bb318d5f3145dd23ffa93f7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytsk/), version: 4.1.3-20140506.linux-x86_64
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pytsk/pytsk-4.1.3-20140506.tar.gz#md5=a0d0c7af34b6873334d48a61295e51eb (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytsk/), version: 4.1.3-20140506
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pytsk/pytsk-4.1.3-20140506.linux-x86_64.tar.gz#md5=dbc9cce02bb318d5f3145dd23ffa93f7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytsk/), version 4.1.3-20140506.linux-x86_64 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pytsk/pytsk-4.1.3-20140506.tar.gz#md5=a0d0c7af34b6873334d48a61295e51eb (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytsk/)
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pytsk/setup.py) egg_info for package pytsk
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/pytsk/setup.py", line 117, in <module>
        raise EnvironmentError('Unable to locate SleuthKit header files.')
    EnvironmentError: Unable to locate SleuthKit header files.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/pytsk/setup.py", line 117, in <module>

    raise EnvironmentError('Unable to locate SleuthKit header files.')

EnvironmentError: Unable to locate SleuthKit header files.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pytsk
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 325, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pytsk
```

After some google-fu and referencing the pytsk troubleshooting documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/py4n6/pytsk/wiki/Troubleshooting) I haven’t found anything that addresses this issue. In my  research I also came across some instructions on an install using the more forthright method of [Debian package tools](https://github.com/py4n6/pytsk/wiki/Building-SleuthKit) instead of apt-get, but this seems to be tailored to development on SleuthKit 4.1.2.

Are there dependencies missing from the pytsk documentation, is this an issue with version conflicts (i.e. a SleuthKit 3.2.3 install trying to pull  4.1.3 from source), or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance, hive mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need the header files, however these aren't installed by default.

apt-get (or whatever) install libtsk